# DAC84018 Texas Instruments

Tags: embedded, esp32, texas-instruments, dac

I am used to Dac81408evm board the board used to spi decimal (digital data)to convert analog output i will try many way of code used to write a register but the output value not change, To check alarm pin and temperature pin output is high,

How to Dac84108 board Alarm off,Ana Temperature pin output reduce.

Hardware or esp32 code to solve